# How to trigger window resize event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a Angular plugin on data table. The container of the data table is resizable, while through the doc I learned that the data table it self will resize when there is a window resize event. In jQuery I know there is a `$(window).trigger()` but I don't know how to do that in angular.

My question is: in parent angular directive, how do I trigger that window resize event?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can trigger `window.resize` event by

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

---

And for listening to `window.resize`, use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) as below example:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
sizeChange(event) {
  console.log('size changed.', event);
}
```

**[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kcasu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this piece of code listening to the `window.resize` event?

Comment: @Zanecat yeah, it is. you can confirm by change the size of the browser window. for the plunker demo, remember to open the console to see the message. :-)

Comment: Well, but I want to trigger this event rather than listen to it.

Comment: @Zanecat well, sorry for misunderstood your question, I have add what you want to my answer.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot.