# Angular - Change CSS property with NgStyle dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have `div` element which I want to show or no depending on the screen size (I know that can be done by mediaqueries, but tried to approach this with Angular). So I got working NgStyle condition
`[ngStyle]="{display: innerWidth < '600' ? 'none' : 'flex'}"` 
when `innerWidth` is variable in the .ts file of this component

```
public innerWidth: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
```

This is working fine, but changing only when I reload the page, so I want to trigger this change dynamically when I resize the browser window, is that possible in similar way?

Comment: You basically need to subscribe to window's resize event and set value for `this.innerWidth` when that event occurs. Checkout here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451974/3965832

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to update the value when the window is resized. You can listen for `window:resize`:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
}
```